# Trouble importing STL produced by VTK

Tags: import, file-format, stl

I am new to blender and am unsuccessfully trying to open an STL file.

Our own [visualization software](http://www.vivoquant.com/) offers STL export via a library called [VTK](http://www.vtk.org), which we can import into other CAD software (e.g. to [feed into a 3D printer](https://blog.invicro.com/2013/07/23/exporting-vq-rois-to-the-real-world/)).

Blender's *Import Stl* function also loads the exported STL file, and I do see the number of vertices, faces, tris, objects, etc. increase, however, I fail to see anything in the view.

I assume this comes from my lack of even basic understanding of how blender works and that for instance the faces are just transparent, or everything is very small or somehow else rendered invisible.

Could one of you please have a quick look at the [STL file](http://www.vivoquant.com/blender/mouse-atlas.zip) and give me a hint of what I am doing wrong?

2. Rendering in our own [VivoQuant software](http://www.vivoquant.com/blender/mouse.png)
3. What I get after import to Blender:

[image: blank startup scene]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The import goes fine, but the model isn't visible in the viewport because the view isn't pointing at it, you could do a few things:

1. zoom out  (<kbd>mouse wheel</kbd>)
2. rotate the view. (<kbd>middle mouse button</kbd>)
3. press <kbd>home</kbd> to View All.
   [image]
4. Use the [*Outliner View*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/The_Outliner) to see if the object imported, then select the object by clicking the name.
   [image]
   With the mouse cursor in the *`3D View`* press <kbd>.</kbd> (period) to focus the view on the selected object.

Comment: Many thanks, I was indeed able to find my mouse now. I did try moving the camera around, just didn't expect it to be off by that much.
Also, I found that the `Origin` functions are very useful; I set the 3D cursor to the center, then used `Origin to 3D Cursor`, and finally `Geometry to Origin` to get the mouse into the center, just in case this helps anybody else.